# Extract WebClient GET response values within a Spring Cloud Gateway filter

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-webclient, spring-mono

My end goal with this is to implement a way to make composite API calls within the body of a gateway route filter. I have a very basic demo application running on port `9000` and exposing a few endpoints. Here is the REST controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/composite")
public class CompositeCallController {

    @GetMapping("/test/one")
    public Map<String, Object> first() {
        Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();
        output.put("response-1-1", "FIRST 1");
        output.put("response-1-2", "FIRST 2");
        output.put("response-1-3", "FIRST 3");
        return output;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/two")
    public Map<String, Object> second() {
        Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();
        output.put("response-2-1", "SECOND 1");
        output.put("response-2-2", "SECOND 2");
        output.put("response-2-3", "SECOND 3");
        return output;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, Object> init() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Both controllers return just a plain Map with a few entries inside. I have a Spring Cloud Gateway application running on a separate port, and I have configured via YML a route that leads to the `localhost:9000/composite` endpoint, which returns a blank map. Then I have a `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory` filter that kicks in and creates two brand new requests towards the two other endpoints in my demo application.

I want to aggregate those two responses into one by transferring them into a new map that I return to the filter chain. Here's how my filter looks:

```java
    public GatewayFilter apply(final Config config) {
        final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig = new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config();
        modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig.setRewriteFunction(Map.class, Map.class, (exchange, body) -> {
            WebClient client = WebClient.create();

            Mono<Map<String, Object>> firstCallMono = client.get()
                    .uri(FIRST_SERVICE_URL)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(json);

            Mono<Map<String, Object>> secondCallMono = client.get()
                    .uri(SECOND_SERVICE_URL)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(json);

            Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();
            Mono.zip(firstCallMono, secondCallMono)
                    .log()
                    .subscribe(v -> {
                        System.out.println("FIRST VALUE = " + v.getT1());
                        System.out.println("SECOND VALUE = " + v.getT2());
                        output.put("1", v.getT1());
                        output.put("2", v.getT2());
                    });

            System.out.println("OUTPUT VALUE 1 = " + output.get("1"));
            System.out.println("OUTPUT VALUE 2 = " + output.get("2"));

            return Mono.just(output);
        });
        return modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory.apply(modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig);
    }
```

The `json` type is defined as `private final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> json = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};`

The URIs are as follows:

```java
public static final String FIRST_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:9000/composite/test/one";
public static final String SECOND_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:9000/composite/test/two";
```

And here's my gateway config for reference:

```yml
logging:
  level:
    reactor:
      netty: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        cloud:
          gateway: TRACE

spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 20MB
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        wiretap: true
      httpserver:
        wiretap: true
      routes:
        - id: composite-call-test
          uri: http://localhost:9000
          predicates:
            - Path=/composite/**
          filters:
            - CompositeApiCallFilter
```

To merge the Monos, I use `Mono.zip()` as it seems to serve just that goal. I've purposefully put two `System.out.println()`s within the `zip()` body to make sure the responses from the above two WebClient requests are actually correct, and it definitely seems so:

```
FIRST VALUE = {response-1-2=FIRST 2, response-1-3=FIRST 3, response-1-1=FIRST 1}
SECOND VALUE = {response-2-3=SECOND 3, response-2-1=SECOND 1, response-2-2=SECOND 2}
```

However, I've also put two console prints after the `zip()` to check if something is populated in the map, and it's completely empty for some reason:

```
OUTPUT VALUE 1 = null
OUTPUT VALUE 2 = null
```

Here's the full console output from the request for reference:

```
2022-05-13 14:53:22.087  INFO 72992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.Zip.1                       : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoZip.ZipCoordinator)
2022-05-13 14:53:22.090  INFO 72992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.Zip.1                       : request(unbounded)
OUTPUT VALUE 1 = null
OUTPUT VALUE 2 = null
2022-05-13 14:53:22.139  INFO 72992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.Zip.1                       : onNext([{response-1-2=FIRST 2, response-1-3=FIRST 3, response-1-1=FIRST 1},{response-2-3=SECOND 3, response-2-1=SECOND 1, response-2-2=SECOND 2}])
FIRST VALUE = {response-1-2=FIRST 2, response-1-3=FIRST 3, response-1-1=FIRST 1}
SECOND VALUE = {response-2-3=SECOND 3, response-2-1=SECOND 1, response-2-2=SECOND 2}
2022-05-13 14:53:22.140  INFO 72992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.Zip.1                       : onComplete()
```

I tried a bunch of other ways of doing the above, for example merging the two `Mono`s into a `Flux` by using `firstCallMono.mergeWith(secondCallMono)` and then subscribing to the resulting `Flux` object and populating the map, but the result is identical.

I also tried putting the two `Mono`s into a `Pair` object and extracting the values like so:

```java
Pair<Mono<Map<String, Object>>, Mono<Map<String, Object>>> pair = new Pair(firstCall, secondCallDTOMono);
pair.getValue0().log().subscribe(v -> output.put("1", v));
pair.getValue1().log().subscribe(v -> output.put("2", v));
```

But again, the `output` map is empty at the end, and I don't understand why. It seems like whatever comes back from the WebClient `.get()` call is of type `MonoFlapMap.FlatMapMain` and I suspect the issue comes from unpacking the values from this type into my regular HashMap, but I don't know how to resolve that issue. I tried using `.map()` and `.flatMap()` but neither worked.

Could someone please let me know how to extract those values?

Comment: Dont `subscribe` the calling client is the subscriber. `return Mono.zip( …, …).flatMap(v -> { …. });` the only reason you should subscribe is if your server is the one initating a call and subscribing to someone elses api.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my issue! I will post an updated answer.

Comment: Next time i’d prefer to write the answer so i get cred for sharing my knowledge and not you taking cred for it.

Comment: That is perfectly understandable, go ahead and post your answer and I'll flag it as the solution. I didn't ask because I noticed most people on here don't really care that much.

Comment: `I didn't ask because I noticed most people on here don't really care that much.` that is highly your personal opinion and in no way a fact. Please dont assume things.

Comment: When you are sure about your answer, why not post it as an answer instead of as a comment? Would make it easier to select it as the right answer.

Comment: Because when i am not sure i post it as a comment, there could easy be more factors into why your code wasn't working. Posting an answer that is faulty is very frowned upon. Posting a comment that then turns out to be correct can then be later converted to an answer.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'm very new to SO and not aware of all those specifics. Please transfer your comment to an answer and I'd be happy to flag it as the answer, because it really helped me.

Comment: its fine, now you know, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of [Toerktumlare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840146/toerktumlare), I was able to make it work properly. Here's the entire filter for reference:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class CompositeApiCallFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CompositeApiCallFilter.Config> {
    public static final String COMPOSITE_TEST_URL = "http://localhost:9000/composite/test/";
    private final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory;
    private final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> json = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
    };

    @Autowired
    public CompositeApiCallFilter(ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory factory) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(final Config config) {
        final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig = new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config();
        modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig.setRewriteFunction(Map.class, Map.class, (exchange, body) -> {
            WebClient client = WebClient.create();

            Mono<Map<String, Object>> firstCallMono = client.get()
                    .uri(COMPOSITE_TEST_URL + "one")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(json);

            Mono<Map<String, Object>> secondCallMono = client.get()
                    .uri(COMPOSITE_TEST_URL + "two")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(json);

            Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();

            return Mono.zip(firstCallMono, secondCallMono)
                    .flatMap(v -> {
                        output.put("1", v.getT1());
                        output.put("2", v.getT2());
                        return Mono.just(output);
                    });
        });

        return modifyResponseBodyFilterFactory.apply(modifyResponseBodyFilterFactoryConfig);
    }

    public static class Config {
    }
}
```

And the respective output in Postman:

```json
{
    "1": {
        "response-1-2": "FIRST 2",
        "response-1-3": "FIRST 3",
        "response-1-1": "FIRST 1"
    },
    "2": {
        "response-2-3": "SECOND 3",
        "response-2-1": "SECOND 1",
        "response-2-2": "SECOND 2"
    }
}
```

Seems like subscribing wasn't necessary at all, just zipping the monos and extracting their values with `flatMap` worked well.